# elasticsearch/logstash regex - get the value after a specific key

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash

There is a problem I struggle with for a while:

I have data in a json format:

```
"documentsList": [{
        "commandScn": "108058599",
        "commandCommitScn": "108058600",
        "commandSequence": "0",
        "commandType": "UPDATE",
        "commandTimestamp": "2017-08-22 14:37:53+03:000",
        "objectDBName": "DEV2",
        "objectSchemaName": "YISHAIN",
        "objectId": "CUSTOMERS",
        "changedFieldsList": [{
                "fieldId": "CUSTOMER_ID",
                "fieldType": "NUMBER",
                "fieldValue": "17",
                "fieldChanged": "N"
            }, {
                "fieldId": "CUSTOMER_FIRST_NAME",
                "fieldType": "VARCHAR2",
                "fieldValue": "Daniel",
                "fieldChanged": "N"
            }, {
                "fieldId": "CUSTOMER_LAST_NAME",
                "fieldType": "VARCHAR2",
                "fieldValue": "Washington",
                "fieldChanged": "N"
            }, {
                "fieldId": "CUSTOMER_COUNTRY",
                "fieldType": "VARCHAR2",
                "fieldValue": "France",
                "fieldChanged": "N"
            }, {
                "fieldId": "CUSTOMER_CITY",
                "fieldType": "VARCHAR2",
                "fieldValue": "La Roche-sur-Yon",
                "fieldChanged": "N"
            }
        }]
}]
```

What I want is to fetch the values of the fields: fieldId, fieldType, fieldValue, fieldChanged etc. I want to aggregate by these terms afterwards in kibana 5.6.

My questions are:

How can I tell grok to fetch everything after a word (because I want the values of the keys, not the leys themselves)?
Does elasticsearch support lookbehind? if so - can anyone give me an example of how to accomplish this?

If elastic's regex doesn't support it, how can I get this done?
If I need to use regex, what will be the why to get the values? What if I had to do that without lookbehind and these methods (javascript regex)?

Thanks!

EDIT:
This is not like this question: [How to parse json in logstash /grok from a text file line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937936/how-to-parse-json-in-logstash-grok-from-a-text-file-line)
because I want to use regex and not json filters.

Comment: EDIT: This is not like this question: How to parse json in logstash /grok from a text file line? because I want to use regex and not json filters.

Comment: You are making a mistake if you want to use regex to do this. It will break horribly at the worst possible time, while the json filter might continue to work even if you json changes.