# Getting multiple fields from message in filebeat and logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, filebeat

I am writing logs into log file from my Django app, from there I am shipping those logs to elasticsearch. Because I want to split the fields as well, I am using logstash between filebeat and elasticsearch.

Here is sample log field:

> 2019-03-19 13:39:06 logfile INFO save_data {'field1': None, 'time':
>   '13:39:06', 'mobile': '9876543210', 'list_item': "[{'item1': 10,
>   'item2': 'path/to/file'}]", 'response': '{some_complicated_json}}',
>   'field2': 'some data', 'date': '19-03-2019', 'field3': 'some other
>   data'}

I tried to write a GROK match pattern but all the fields are going into `message` field :

```
%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:temp_date}%{SPACE} %{WORD:logfile} %{LOGLEVEL:level} %{WORD:save_data} %{GREEDYDATA:message}
```

How can I write GROK match pattern which can decompose above log entry.

Comment: The json in the logs have a fixed structure?

Comment: @NishantSaini no, different fields in the json might come.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33937936/how-to-parse-json-in-logstash-grok-from-a-text-file-line

Comment: @NishantSaini thanks a ton, that helped.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you could do this with Grok, but the way we do it is with a [json processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/json-processor.html) in elastic [ingest node pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html). Something like this:

```
{
    "my-log-pipeline": {
        "description": "My log pipeline",
        "processors": [{
            "json": {
                "field": "message",
                "target_field": "messageFields"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Then you just need to tell your source (filebeat/logstash) to use this pipeline when ingesting.